# React Native Firebase Analytics: second argment must be an object

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I am trying to implement Firebase Analytics into my React Native app, and I want to log an event every time a user selected a certain category in my app:

```
categoryPressed(category) {
   console.log('selected: ', category.props.title)
   //firebase.analytics().
   firebase.analytics().logEvent('Category', String(category.props.title))

   this.props.navigation.navigate('ItemOverview', {
       category: category,
     });
}
```

This, however, outputs the next error:

```
analytics.logEvent(): Second optional argument 'params' must be an object if provided
```

The documentation doesn't say anything about this. I tried putting my string in an array, which doesn't help either.

Does anyone know what the proper way of logging an event with parameters is in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

It says that params must be an object
https://rnfirebase.io/reference/analytics#logEvent

Example:

```
const ecommerce = {
    promotions: [{
      item_id: 'sku1234',
      item_name: 'Android Jogger Sweatpants',
      item_category: 'Apparel/Men/Pants',
      item_variant: 'Blue',
      item_brand: 'Google',
      price: 39.99,
      currency: 'USD',
      quantity: 1
    }]
  }
  await firebase.analytics().logEvent('add_to_cart', ecommerce);
```

Comment: please change your reference link, it does not exist anymore.